# I want to upload camera image file in folder on google drive from crdova android application using javascript REST api

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am getting byte code of image. but how to pass this byte code on google drive?

Comment: What is "byte code"? Can you include `javascript` that you have tried at Question? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i'm using cordova plugin for image capture.

Comment: function captureUniPhoto() {

 navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoUniSuccess, photoOnFail, {
  quality : 70,
  destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,

 });
} In above code 'onPhotoSuccess' getting image data or saved image path. but i want upload this image on google drive. so what can i do?

Comment: Can you include `javascript` that you have tried at Question?

Comment: Yes i have included the javascript..